# php curl multi strange behaviour that skip some results

Tags: php, curl, foreach

I make multiple requests to an API endpoint by using curl_multi_exec(), exactly as follows:

```
function curl_multi ( array $apiUrls ) {

    $multiHandles = [];
    $results = [];

    // Initialize multi-handle
    $multiHandle = curl_multi_init();

    foreach ($apiUrls as $item => $url) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);

        // Set cURL options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 ); 
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN, true); 
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  ''); 

        // Add individual handle to the multi-handle
        curl_multi_add_handle($multiHandle, $ch);

        $multiHandles[$item] = $ch;
    }

    // Execute multi-handle requests
    do {
        $status = curl_multi_exec($multiHandle, $active);
        curl_multi_select($multiHandle); // Non-blocking wait
    } while ($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $active);

    // Process responses and close handles
    foreach ($multiHandles as $item => $ch) {
        $response = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);
        if ($response === false) { apiErr( "error $item > $apiUrls[$item]", curl_error($ch) );  } 
        else { $results[$item] = json_decode( $response, true ); }

        curl_multi_remove_handle($multiHandle, $ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    // Close the multi-handle
    curl_multi_close($multiHandle);

    return $results;
}

foreach( $items as $item ) { $apiUrls[$item] = "https://..."; } 
$res = curl_multi ( $apiUrls );

foreach( $items as $item ) {
 // do something with each $res[$item]
 // some items are skipped, even if they exists!
}
```

Everything works perfectly, except in the second foreach, when I loop to "do something with each $res[$item]" **sometime it skip some random items**!

Even more strange, I have double checked everything, I don't get any error, and **all items exists**! In fact, if I run a third foreach below, all items works!

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: There are too many “some", can you be more specific?

Comment: We'd probably need to see the code in the second foreach loop...

Comment: If the second foreach is supposed to operate on `$res`, it might make sense to not look at `$items`.

Answer (score 1):

The docs have a slightly different while loop:

```php
//execute the multi handle
do {
    $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
    if ($active) {
        // Wait a short time for more activity
        curl_multi_select($mh);
    }
} while ($active && $status == CURLM_OK);
```

Digging into `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM` it looks to be deprecated, so maybe that is why you are running into problems here and all the third loop is doing is giving more time for things to complete.